# broken package when trying to install wine

Tags: wine, synaptic, aptitude

I have ubuntu 16.04 and I am a total linux newb. I am trying to install winehq-stable by following the instruction on https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

I tried synaptic which indicated I have a broken package. I then tried aptitude with the following output:

```
sudo aptitude install winehq-stable

The following NEW packages will be installed:

gcc-5-base:i386{a} gcc-6-base:i386{a} gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386{a} libasn1-8-heimdal:i386{a}
  libasound2:i386{a} libasound2-plugins:i386{a} libasyncns0:i386{a} libavahi-client3:i386{a}
  libavahi-common-data:i386{a} libavahi-common3:i386{a} libbsd0:i386{a} libc6:i386{a} libcap2:i386{a}
  libcapi20-3{a} libcapi20-3:i386{a} libcdparanoia0:i386{a} libcomerr2:i386{a} libcups2:i386{a}
  libdb5.3:i386{a} libdbus-1-3:i386{ab} libdrm-amdgpu1:i386{ab} libdrm-intel1:i386{ab}
  libdrm-nouveau2:i386{ab} libdrm-radeon1:i386{ab} libdrm2:i386{ab} libedit2:i386{a} libelf1:i386{a}
  libexif12:i386{a} libexpat1:i386{a} libffi6:i386{a} libflac8:i386{a} libfontconfig1:i386{a}
  libfreetype6:i386{a} libgcc1:i386{a} libgcrypt20:i386{a} libgd3:i386{a} libgl1-mesa-dri:i386{ab}
  libgl1-mesa-glx:i386{ab} libglapi-mesa:i386{ab} libglib2.0-0:i386{ab} libglu1-mesa:i386{a} libgmp10:i386{a}
  libgnutls30:i386{a} libgpg-error0:i386{a} libgphoto2-6:i386{a} libgphoto2-port12:i386{a} libgpm2:i386{a}
  libgsm1:i386{a} libgssapi-krb5-2:i386{ab} libgssapi3-heimdal:i386{a} libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386{a}
  libgstreamer1.0-0:i386{ab} libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386{a} libheimbase1-heimdal:i386{a}
  libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386{a} libhogweed4:i386{a} libhx509-5-heimdal:i386{a} libicu55:i386{a}
  libidn11:i386{a} libieee1284-3:i386{a} libjack-jackd2-0:i386{a} libjbig0:i386{a} libjpeg-turbo8:i386{a}
  libjpeg8:i386{a} libjson-c2:i386{a} libk5crypto3:i386{ab} libkeyutils1:i386{a} libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386{a}
  libkrb5-3:i386{ab} libkrb5support0:i386{ab} liblcms2-2:i386{a} libldap-2.4-2:i386{a} libllvm3.8:i386{ab}
  libltdl7:i386{a} liblzma5:i386{a} libmpg123-0{a} libmpg123-0:i386{a} libncurses5:i386{a} libnettle6:i386{a}
  libodbc1{a} libodbc1:i386{a} libogg0:i386{a} libopenal-data{a} libopenal1{a} libopenal1:i386{a}
  libopus0:i386{a} liborc-0.4-0:i386{a} libosmesa6{ab} libosmesa6:i386{a} libp11-kit0:i386{ab}
  libpcap0.8:i386{a} libpciaccess0:i386{a} libpcre3:i386{a} libpng12-0:i386{a} libpulse0:i386{ab}
  libroken18-heimdal:i386{a} libsamplerate0:i386{a} libsane:i386{a} libsasl2-2:i386{a}
  libsasl2-modules:i386{a} libsasl2-modules-db:i386{a} libselinux1:i386{a} libsndfile1:i386{a}
  libspeexdsp1:i386{a} libsqlite3-0:i386{a} libssl1.0.0:i386{a} libstdc++6:i386{a} libsystemd0:i386{ab}
  libtasn1-6:i386{a} libtheora0:i386{a} libtiff5:i386{a} libtinfo5:i386{a} libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386{a}
  libudev1:i386{ab} libusb-1.0-0:i386{a} libv4l-0:i386{a} libv4lconvert0:i386{a} libvisual-0.4-0:i386{a}
  libvorbis0a:i386{a} libvorbisenc2:i386{a} libvpx3:i386{a} libwind0-heimdal:i386{a} libwrap0:i386{a}
  libx11-6:i386{a} libx11-xcb1:i386{a} libxau6:i386{a} libxcb-dri2-0:i386{a} libxcb-dri3-0:i386{a}
  libxcb-glx0:i386{a} libxcb-present0:i386{a} libxcb-sync1:i386{a} libxcb1:i386{a} libxcomposite1:i386{a}
  libxcursor1:i386{a} libxdamage1:i386{a} libxdmcp6:i386{a} libxext6:i386{a} libxfixes3:i386{a}
  libxi6:i386{a} libxinerama1:i386{a} libxml2:i386{a} libxpm4:i386{a} libxrandr2:i386{a} libxrender1:i386{a}
  libxshmfence1:i386{a} libxslt1.1:i386{a} libxxf86vm1:i386{a} wine-stable{a} wine-stable-amd64{a}
  wine-stable-i386:i386{a} winehq-stable zlib1g:i386{a}

0 packages upgraded, 152 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 98.9 MB of archives. After unpacking 664 MB will be used.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libkrb5-3 : Breaks: libkrb5-3:i386 (!= 1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 1.13.2+dfsg-5 is to be installed.
 libkrb5-3:i386 : Breaks: libkrb5-3 (!= 1.13.2+dfsg-5) but 1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2 is installed.
 libgssapi-krb5-2 : Breaks: libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 (!= 1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 1.13.2+dfsg-5 is to be installed.
 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 : Breaks: libgssapi-krb5-2 (!= 1.13.2+dfsg-5) but 1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2 is installed.
 libdbus-1-3 : Breaks: libdbus-1-3:i386 (!= 1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3) but 1.10.6-1ubuntu3.1 is to be installed.
 libdbus-1-3:i386 : Breaks: libdbus-1-3 (!= 1.10.6-1ubuntu3.1) but 1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3 is installed.
 libdrm-nouveau2 : Breaks: libdrm-nouveau2:i386 (!= 2.4.70-1~ubuntu16.04.1) but 2.4.67-1 is to be installed.
 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 : Breaks: libdrm-nouveau2 (!= 2.4.67-1) but 2.4.70-1~ubuntu16.04.1 is installed.
 libsystemd0 : Breaks: libsystemd0:i386 (!= 229-4ubuntu16) but 229-4ubuntu10 is to be installed.
 libsystemd0:i386 : Breaks: libsystemd0 (!= 229-4ubuntu10) but 229-4ubuntu16 is installed.
 libglapi-mesa : Breaks: libglapi-mesa:i386 (!= 12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) but 11.2.0-1ubuntu2 is to be installed.
 libglapi-mesa:i386 : Breaks: libglapi-mesa (!= 11.2.0-1ubuntu2) but 12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 is installed.
 libk5crypto3 : Breaks: libk5crypto3:i386 (!= 1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 1.13.2+dfsg-5 is to be installed.
 libk5crypto3:i386 : Breaks: libk5crypto3 (!= 1.13.2+dfsg-5) but 1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2 is installed.
 libudev1 : Breaks: libudev1:i386 (!= 229-4ubuntu16) but 229-4ubuntu10 is to be installed.
 libudev1:i386 : Breaks: libudev1 (!= 229-4ubuntu10) but 229-4ubuntu16 is installed.
 libllvm3.8 : Breaks: libllvm3.8:i386 (!= 1:3.8-2ubuntu4) but 1:3.8-2ubuntu1 is to be installed.
 libllvm3.8:i386 : Breaks: libllvm3.8 (!= 1:3.8-2ubuntu1) but 1:3.8-2ubuntu4 is installed.
 libdrm-amdgpu1 : Breaks: libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 (!= 2.4.70-1~ubuntu16.04.1) but 2.4.67-1 is to be installed.
 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 : Breaks: libdrm-amdgpu1 (!= 2.4.67-1) but 2.4.70-1~ubuntu16.04.1 is installed.
 libpulse0 : Breaks: libpulse0:i386 (!= 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.2) but 1:8.0-0ubuntu3 is to be installed.
 libpulse0:i386 : Breaks: libpulse0 (!= 1:8.0-0ubuntu3) but 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.2 is installed.
 libkrb5support0 : Breaks: libkrb5support0:i386 (!= 1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 1.13.2+dfsg-5 is to be installed.
 libkrb5support0:i386 : Breaks: libkrb5support0 (!= 1.13.2+dfsg-5) but 1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2 is installed.
 libdrm2 : Breaks: libdrm2:i386 (!= 2.4.70-1~ubuntu16.04.1) but 2.4.67-1 is to be installed.
 libdrm2:i386 : Breaks: libdrm2 (!= 2.4.67-1) but 2.4.70-1~ubuntu16.04.1 is installed.
 libgl1-mesa-dri : Breaks: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (!= 12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) but 11.2.0-1ubuntu2 is to be installe                                                                                    d.
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Breaks: libgl1-mesa-dri (!= 11.2.0-1ubuntu2) but 12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 is installed.
 libosmesa6 : Depends: libglapi-mesa (= 11.2.0-1ubuntu2) but 12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 is installed.
 libgl1-mesa-glx : Breaks: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (!= 12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) but 11.2.0-1ubuntu2 is to be installe                                                                                    d.
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Breaks: libgl1-mesa-glx (!= 11.2.0-1ubuntu2) but 12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 is installed.
 libdrm-intel1 : Breaks: libdrm-intel1:i386 (!= 2.4.70-1~ubuntu16.04.1) but 2.4.67-1 is to be installed.
 libdrm-intel1:i386 : Breaks: libdrm-intel1 (!= 2.4.67-1) but 2.4.70-1~ubuntu16.04.1 is installed.
 libp11-kit0 : Breaks: libp11-kit0:i386 (!= 0.23.2-5~ubuntu16.04.1) but 0.23.2-3 is to be installed.
 libp11-kit0:i386 : Breaks: libp11-kit0 (!= 0.23.2-3) but 0.23.2-5~ubuntu16.04.1 is installed.
 libdrm-radeon1 : Breaks: libdrm-radeon1:i386 (!= 2.4.70-1~ubuntu16.04.1) but 2.4.67-1 is to be installed.
 libdrm-radeon1:i386 : Breaks: libdrm-radeon1 (!= 2.4.67-1) but 2.4.70-1~ubuntu16.04.1 is installed.
 libgstreamer1.0-0 : Breaks: libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 (!= 1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1) but 1.8.0-1 is to be installed.
 libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 : Breaks: libgstreamer1.0-0 (!= 1.8.0-1) but 1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1 is installed.
 libglib2.0-0 : Breaks: libglib2.0-0:i386 (!= 2.48.2-0ubuntu1) but 2.48.0-1ubuntu4 is to be installed.
 libglib2.0-0:i386 : Breaks: libglib2.0-0 (!= 2.48.0-1ubuntu4) but 2.48.2-0ubuntu1 is installed.

open: 465; closed: 6205; defer: 167; conflict: 253                                                               o                                                                                    
Internal error: found 2 (choice -> promotion) mappings for a single choice.
open: 686; closed: 7695; defer: 172; conflict: 258                                                               O                                                                                    Internal error: found 2 (choice -> promotion) mappings for a single choice.
open: 1010; closed: 8905; defer: 173; conflict: 260                                                              o                                                                                    Internal error: found 2 (choice -> promotion) mappings for a single choice.
open: 1262; closed: 10283; defer: 173; conflict: 260                                                             .                                                                                    Internal error: found 2 (choice -> promotion) mappings for a single choice.
Internal error: found 2 (choice -> promotion) mappings for a single choice.
open: 1496; closed: 11345; defer: 174; conflict: 261                                                             o                                                                                    Internal error: found 2 (choice -> promotion) mappings for a single choice.
open: 1802; closed: 12880; defer: 175; conflict: 262                                                             O                                                                                    Internal error: found 2 (choice -> promotion) mappings for a single choice.
Internal error: found 2 (choice -> promotion) mappings for a single choice.
open: 2347; closed: 14078; defer: 175; conflict: 262                                                             o                                                                                    Internal error: found 2 (choice -> promotion) mappings for a single choice.
open: 2371; closed: 15169; defer: 175; conflict: 262                                                             .                                                                                    Internal error: found 2 (choice -> promotion) mappings for a single choice.
open: 2526; closed: 16379; defer: 175; conflict: 262                                                             o                                                                                    Internal error: found 2 (choice -> promotion) mappings for a single choice.
open: 2821; closed: 18012; defer: 175; conflict: 262                                                             O                                                                                    Internal error: found 2 (choice -> promotion) mappings for a single choice.
open: 3009; closed: 19361; defer: 177; conflict: 264                                                             o                                                                                    Internal error: found 2 (choice -> promotion) mappings for a single choice.
Internal error: found 2 (choice -> promotion) mappings for a single choice.
open: 3648; closed: 21957; defer: 177; conflict: 264                                                             o                                                                                    Internal error: found 2 (choice -> promotion) mappings for a single choice.
Internal error: found 2 (choice -> promotion) mappings for a single choice.
open: 4265; closed: 23291; defer: 180; conflict: 268                                                             O                                                                                    Internal error: found 2 (choice -> promotion) mappings for a single choice.
Internal error: found 2 (choice -> promotion) mappings for a single choice.
open: 4358; closed: 24450; defer: 180; conflict: 268                                                             o                                                                                    Internal error: found 2 (choice -> promotion) mappings for a single choice.
open: 4763; closed: 26976; defer: 180; conflict: 268                                                             o                                                                                    Internal error: found 2 (choice -> promotion) mappings for a single choice.
Internal error: found 2 (choice -> promotion) mappings for a single choice.
open: 4995; closed: 28493; defer: 181; conflict: 269                                                             O                                                                                    Internal error: found 2 (choice -> promotion) mappings for a single choice.
open: 5318; closed: 29751; defer: 181; conflict: 269                                                             o                                                                                    Internal error: found 2 (choice -> promotion) mappings for a single choice.
open: 5659; closed: 32516; defer: 184; conflict: 273                                                             o                                                                                    Internal error: found 2 (choice -> promotion) mappings for a single choice.
open: 7297; closed: 36995; defer: 186; conflict: 275                                                             .                                                                                    Internal error: found 2 (choice -> promotion) mappings for a single choice.
No solution found within the allotted time.  Try harder? [Y/n]
```

no idea how to proceed. Any help would be highly appreciated in both understand what aptitude mean by the errors and how to fix it.
Amish

Comment: you have to enable multi-arch first `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` then `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: That did not help